# docker file unknown instruction

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following in my docker file.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/home/dev/juju-1.0.0.jar",
  "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true",
  "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=4545",
  "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false",
  "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false",
  "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false",
  "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=4545",
  "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname= prod.juju.nomadlogicapp.com"]
```

I am looking to add the default jdk supplied profiler on my container.

The problem is that docker complaints that instructions such as : -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true are unknown.

Comment: Please [edit] to show the precise formatting. On the desktop version of this site, paste your code, then select the pasted block and type ctrl-K to correctly format your code with indentations preserved. I'm guessing you have forgotten to backslash-espace the newlines.

Comment: It doe snot seem to fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to either remove or escape the linefeeds in that step. The ENTRYPOINT step ends when it reaches the end of the line, not when it reaches the end of the json array syntax. To span multiple lines, escape the linefeed with a `\` at the end of the line.